# How can optimize parameters to a set of given data by fitting a function that contains a numerically calculated integer?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy, integer, curve-fitting

I want to fit a function f(x; k_1, k_2) where f is a function that contains a numerically calculated integer with parameters k_1 and k_2 that I want to optimize for a set of given data.

Below is the definition of the function:

[image]

Below is how the function f(x) looks like for arbitrary fixed values of k_1 and k_2:

```
def dgdx(g,x):
    k_1 = 1e7
    k_2 = 10
    return k_1*g**(1/2)-k_2*g
g_0 = 1e10
x = np.linspace(0,1,101)
g = odeint(dgdx,g_0,x)
a=10
b=100
f = a*(g)**(1/2)+b
plt.plot(x, f, '-')
```

[image]

My question is in the title. To solve it I wrote the code below but it leads the kernel to die:

```
def dgdx(x,k_1,k_2):
    return k_1*(g(x,k_1,k_2))**(1/2)-k_2*g(x,k_1,k_2)

def g(x,k_1,k_2):
    return quad(dgdx,0,1, args=(k_1,k_2))

def f(x,k_1,k_2):
    a=10
    b=100
    return a*(g(x,k_1,k_2))**(1/2)+b

x_given = np.linspace(0,1,101)
y_given = f(x_given,1e7,10)+0.2*np.random.normal(size=len(x_given))

params, extras = curve_fit(f,x_given,y_given)

print("k_1=%g, k_2=%g" % (params[0], params[1]))

plt.plot(x_given, y_given, 'o')
plt.plot(x_given, f(x,params[0], params[1]))
```

Alternatively, I also tried the code below, but I got the error: maximum recursion depth exceeded.

```
def dgdx(x,k_1,k_2):
    return k_1*(g(x,k_1,k_2))**(1/2)-k_2*g(x,k_1,k_2)

def g(x,k_1,k_2):
    return odeint(dgdx(x,k_1,k_2),g_0,x)

def f(x,k_1,k_2):
    a=10
    b=100
    return a*(g(x,k_1,k_2))**(1/2)+b

x_given = np.linspace(0,1,101)
y_given = f(x_given,1e7,10)+0.2*np.random.normal(size=len(x_given))

params, extras = curve_fit(f,x_given,y_given)

print("k_1=%g, k_2=%g" % (params[0], params[1]))

plt.plot(x_given, y_given, 'o')
plt.plot(x_given, f(x,params[0], params[1]))
```

Comment: f calls g which calls dgdx which calls g too, so there is a cycle in the calls that will never end since there is no conditionals to stop it. The result is the recursion error you get. I do not clearly understand what you want to do but you have to break the cycle.

Comment: Dear Jérôme, thanks for your suggestions. There is a simple way to avoid the recursive error (see below) but that does not solve my problem which concerns the optimization of 2 parameters.

Comment: `g = odeint(dgdx,g_0,x)`

Comment: and `def dgdx(x,g):
    return k_1*g**(1/2)-k_2*g`

Comment: Can you verify that the equation that you show for *g(x)* is correct?  I.e. check that the right-hand side is the definite integral from 0 to 1, and the integrand as shown is correct.  If so, there is a simple solution to the problem (and using `odeint` like you have in the code is not correct).

Comment: @Warren. Hi Warren, thanks for your comment. I would be curious to know what you have in mind. To answer your question, yes, the g(x) expression is correct. The integral has an analytical solution (no need to use odeint), however, my original equation is more complex and has no analytical solution (I show this one for convenience). Hope this is useful.

Comment: Your equation for g(x) has the constant solutions g(x) = 0 and g(x) = (k1/(1+k2))**2.  The full name for the class of problems to which the equation belongs is "nonlinear homogeneous [Fredholm integral equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fredholm_integral_equation) of the second kind". It is a very simple example from that class, and because the right side of the equation is independent of x (it is a definite integral), deriving those two constant solutions requires just a little bit of algebra.  Solving `g'(x) = k1*sqrt(g(x)) - k2*g(x)` will not give a solution to the integral equation.

Comment: @Warren. Thanks. I edited my question to show the solution of g'(x).

Comment: @Stephane. In your question, instead of a graph a numerical data is necessary. Without data one cannot run the software and check different code.

Answer (score 0):

The library lmfit enables fitting ODEs.